# Hilt implement issue - Expected @HiltAndroidApp to have a value

Tags: android, kotlin, dependency-injection, android-gradle-plugin, dagger-hilt

I'm having a issue implement Hilt on android app...

The error is:

> Expected @HiltAndroidApp to have a value. Did you forget to apply the Gradle Plugin?

Project gradle file

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        //Hilt
        classpath 'com.google.dagger:hilt-android-gradle-plugin:2.38.1'

        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.4"
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.5.20"
    }
}
```

Model gradle file

```
id 'kotlin-kapt'
id 'dagger.hilt.android.plugin'

dependencies {

    def dagger_hilt_android = "2.38.1"

    implementation("com.google.dagger:hilt-android:$dagger_hilt_android")
    kapt("com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler:$dagger_hilt_android")
}
```

Comment: Did you annotate your custom `Application` with the specified annotation and referenced it into your `AndroidManifest.xml`?

Comment: Yeah, I did that already but so it didn't solve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is an issue with `Kotlin-gradle-plugin: 1.5.20` as mentioned here `https://github.com/google/dagger/issues/2684`. Try upgrading your plugin to `1.5.21`, and it will work.

Comment: You're right, it was because of **v1.5.20**.
Now it is working properly

Answer (score 3):

Mohmd.h.bh,

Try applying this plugin in your build.gradle of your Android Gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.dagger.hilt.android'
android {
  // .......
}
```

I don't think you need to change the version of the **kotlin-gradle-plugin**

Regards